# Conditional save return on Gutenberg Block

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I am creating a "*Trigger Button*" or CTA button if you want to call it that way. The user can choose if it should be a download or a normal redirect. If it is a download, I want the block to add a `download` at the end of the anchor tag

`<a href="#" download>foo</a>`

**How would I let the save return check if the user choose `btntype` `download` and change the anchor tag based on that?**

basically what I need is a working version of this logic: `if btntype === download { <a href="#" download>foo</a> } else { <a href="#">foo</a> };`

Here is my full block code for the trigger button

```
/**
 * WP Dependency
 */
import { URLInput } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const RichText = wp.editor.RichText;
const { PanelBody, PanelRow, SelectControl } = wp.components;
const { 
    InspectorControls,
    URLinput,
} = wp.editor;


/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import './style.scss';

/**
 * Register block
 */
registerBlockType( 're-blockz/btn',
    {
        title: wp.i18n.__( 'Trigger Button', 're-blockz' ),
        category: 're-blockz',
        icon: 'button',
        attributes: {
            btntitle: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'html',
                selector: '.btntitle',
            },
            btntext: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'html',
                selector: '.btntext',
            },
            icontype: {
                type: 'string',
                default: 'chevron_right',
            },
            btntype: {
                type: 'string',
                default: 'rel',
            },
            btncolor: {
                type: 'string',
                default: 'blue',
            },
            btnurl: {
                type: 'string',
            }
        },
        supports: {
            html: false,
        },

        edit( props ) {
            const {
                attributes,
                className,
                setAttributes,
            } = props;

            const {
                btntitle,
                btntext,
                btnurl,
                btncolor,
                btntype,
                icontype,
            } = attributes;

            return (
                <div className={className}>
                    <InspectorControls>
                        <PanelBody
                            title="Button Einstellungen"
                            initialOpen={true}
                        >
                            <PanelRow>
                                <URLInput
                                        label="Link auswählen:"
                                        className={ className }
                                        value={ btnurl }
                                        onChange={ ( btnurl, post ) => setAttributes( { btnurl, btntext: (post && post.title) || 'Link hinzufügen' } ) }
                                    />
                            </PanelRow>
                            <PanelRow>
                                <SelectControl
                                    label="Link-typ wählen"
                                    value={attributes.icontype}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: "Weiterleitung", value: 'chevron_right'},
                                        {label: "Beitrag", value: 'notes'},
                                        {label: "Hervorhebung", value: 'star_rate'},
                                        {label: "Touch", value: 'touch_app'},
                                        {label: "Download", value: 'get_app'}
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(newval) => setAttributes({ icontype: newval })}
                                />
                                <SelectControl
                                    label="Klick-Verhalten"
                                    value={attributes.btntype}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: "Verlinkung", value: 'rel'},
                                        {label: "Download", value: 'download'}
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(newval) => setAttributes({ btntype: newval })}
                                />
                                <SelectControl
                                    label="Button Farbe"
                                    value={attributes.btncolor}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: "Blau", value: 'c_blue'},
                                        {label: "Gelb", value: 'c_yellow'}
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(newval) => setAttributes({ btncolor: newval })}
                                />
                            </PanelRow>
                        </PanelBody>
                    </InspectorControls>
                    <div class="btn-trigger">
                        <div class="btninner">
                            <div class="btnleft">
                                <RichText
                                    tagName="h3"
                                    value={ btntitle }
                                    className="btntitle"
                                    onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { btntitle: value } ) }
                                    placeholder={ __( 'Titel des Button ...', 're-blockz' ) }
                                    keepPlaceholderOnFocus
                                />
                                <RichText
                                    tagName="p"
                                    value={ btntext }
                                    className="btntext"
                                    onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { btntext: value } ) }
                                    placeholder={ __( 'Text des Button ...', 're-blockz' ) }
                                    keepPlaceholderOnFocus
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btnright">
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <span class="material-icons">{ icontype }</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        },

        save( { attributes } ) {
            const {
                btntitle,
                btntext,
                btnurl,
                icontype,
                btncolor,
                btntype,
            } = attributes;
            return (
                <a href={ btnurl } class="btn-trigger" { btntype }>
                    <div class="btninner">
                        <div class="btnleft">
                            <RichText.Content
                                tagName="h3"
                                className="btntitle"
                                value={ btntitle }
                            />
                            <RichText.Content
                                tagName="p"
                                className="btntext"
                                value={ btntext }
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className={ btncolor }>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <span class="material-icons">{ icontype }</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            );
        },
    }
);
```

in this code `btntype` at the end of the anchor tag throws me a expectation error, tho, just to mention, this was my try to do a working rough and dirty quick fix for the problem until I would have more time to read into the topic.

```
Syntax error: C:/0-dev/xxx/re/blocks/src/button/index.js: Unexpected token, expected ... (163:45)

  161 |             } = attributes;
  162 |                         return (
> 163 |                                 <a href={ btnurl } class="btn-trigger" { btntype }>
      |                                                                          ^
  164 |                                         <div class="btninner">
  165 |                                                 <div class="btnleft">
  166 |                                                         <RichText.Content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your `btntype` attribute as type `boolean` and set its default to `false` (maybe better rename it to `download` then ;). And change it to `true` when the user selects the download option.
If you want to conditionally add the `download` attribute in your save functions' JSX use this syntax: `<a href={ btnurl } className="btn-trigger" download={ btntype }>` and it will only add the `download` attribute when the condition is truthy.

Comment: Although React now accepts class as attribute, it would be more correctly to write className instead of class
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989454/class-vs-classname-in-react-16/46991278

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was too focused on the problem in question. I corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: How about using `download= { 'download' === btntype }` without changing the type of the `btntype` attribute?..

Comment: @Sally CJs solution is even smarter as it needs no refactoring (and as you're using a select control for the attribute). Switching to a boolean might be more convenient if you would use a toggle switch for the `download` attribute. 
In the end you need an expression that resolves to `true` or `false` and the `download` attribute will be conditionally added or not.

Comment: small correction: [...] if you would use a toggle switch for the `btntype` attribute [...]

Comment: @SallyCJ that helped a lot. Thank you!